# [Android]ListView notifyDataSetChanged Update error

Tags: android, listview

Please have a look at my code,when I update it ,it gives error out.

```
//definition
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> item;
private SimpleAdapter listItemAdapter;
//initialization

listItemAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, item,R.layout.list_item, 
new String[] { "name", "id", "houseNum","meterValue" }, 
new int[] { R.id.item_name,R.id.item_id, R.id.item_house_num,R.id.item_meter_value });
readingMeterList.setAdapter(listItemAdapter);
...

//definition
HashMap<String, Object> map = Activity.this.item.get(index);
map.put("meterValue", String.format("%.2f", meterValue));
item.set(index, map);
listItemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

and the error message is :[click here to see the big picture](http://img.bbs.csdn.net/upload/201306/03/1370223903_960018.png)

Anyone know how to solve this please help me ,thanks advance.

Comment: Please post the full error message.

Comment: @Juan please look it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
listItemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This piece of code should be placed in runOnUiThread().
You can only call a UI-impacted method from UI thread.

```
runOnUIThread(new Runnable(){
// override method
// and put your code there.
})
```